# Losing environment info when using /usr/bin/sudo and /bin/bash

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, environment-variables

My question is why do I lose environment information like `$PATH` when running the following command:

```
/usr/bin/sudo -H -u <user> /bin/bash -l -c '<command>'
```

I'm trying to add the `/mnt/anaconda` path to this command. So what I tried doing was to add in the `~/.bashrc` for the user:

```
export PATH="/mnt/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Also configured in `visudo`

```
Defaults        env_keep = "PATH"
```

But none of those changes took effect, do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: You ran a non-interactive shell. The first thing that the default `.bashrc` checks is if it is an interactive shell, and if not, quits. Your modification to `.bashrc`therefore has no effect on a non-interactive shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a command in `bash` via `-c` option, a non-interactive shell is spawned. The `~/.bashrc` file is sourced for non-login interactive shells (and also for login interactive shells, sourced from `~/.profile`). The main point is interactivity.

The `~/.bashrc` file has the following snippet at the start :

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

This means check the shell options by `$-`, if the shell is not interactive (no `i` flag), exit from `~/.bashrc` file.

So as you are spawning a non-interactive shell via `bash -c`, the `PATH` you have set at the end won't be read.

You have few options :

- Use the `-i` option of `bash` so that `bash` behaves as an interactive shell and reads the `~/.bashrc` file :

  ```
  /usr/bin/sudo -H -u <user> /bin/bash -i -c '<command>'
  ```
- As you were using the `-l` option which tells `bash` to behave as a login shell, you can put the `PATH` in `~/.profile` so that it will be `source`-ed. Note that this might not a good option considering your need.
- Another very very bad option would be to put `PATH` at the very start of the `~/.bashrc` file, before the interactivity check snippet.